# How to deserialize non-array json to child class that implements List<T>?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have the following class:

```
public class PagedClientModelList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
}
```

Two different json strings will be deserialized into an instance of this object:

- The http content of an api GET request will be deserialized to `List<T>`
- An "X-Pagination" header of the api GET request will be deserialized to the 4 properties of the derived type `PagedClientModelList<T>`

Deserializing to `List<T>` is no problem:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PagedClientModelList<Person>>
                 (httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

for json string:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Hans"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Peter"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Max"
  }
]
```

However, when I want to deserialize the header, which is a non-array json, the jsonConverter wants to deserialze again to `List<T>` and throws an exception, but I need to serialize it to the child class `PagedClientModelList<T>`:

```
if (httpResponseMessage.Headers.TryGetValues("X-Pagination", out var xPagination))
{
    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PagedClientModelList<Person>>(xPagination.First());

    // throws exception: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type [... because it requires json array]
}
```

for the corresponding header value:

```
{
  "totalCount": 12,
  "pageSize": 3,
  "currentPage": 1,
  "totalPages": 4
}
```

How can I deserialize a non-array json to a child class that implements `List<T>`?

Comment: Do you really need to derive from List<T>??

Comment: What else do you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here's an alternative, changing slightly your models:

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PagedClientModelList<T> where T : class, new()
{
    [JsonProperty("totalCount")]
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pageSize")]
    public int PageSize { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("currentPage")]
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("totalPages")]
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("content")]
    public List<T> Content { get; set; }

    public PagedClientModelList()
    {
        Content = new List<T>();
    }
}
```

Testing the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string header = @"{
""totalCount"": 12,
""pageSize"": 3,
""currentPage"": 1,
""totalPages"": 4
}";

        string content = @"[
{
    ""id"": 1,
    ""name"": ""Hans""
},
{
    ""id"": 2,
    ""name"": ""Peter""
},
{
    ""id"": 3,
    ""name"": ""Max""
}
]";

        var modelList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PagedClientModelList<Person>>(header);
        modelList.Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(content);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input! :-) It is similar to my workaround where I encapsulated the header into its own field whereas you encapsulated the content into its own field.

Comment: Np, I'm glad I could help :-)

Answer (score -1):

In order to move forward, I implemented the following workaround:

```
public class PagedClientModelList<T> : List<T>
{
    public PaginationMetadata PaginationMetadata { get; set; }
}

public class PaginationMetadata
{
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages  { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am able to deserialize without any problems:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PagedClientModelList<Person>>
                 (httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

if (httpResponseMessage.Headers.TryGetValues("X-Pagination", out var xPagination))
{
    result.PaginationMetadata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaginationMetadata>(xPagination.First());
}
```